# 12v DC motor not running on 12v battery?

Tags: power-supply, dc, dc-motor, 12v

I don't know anything about electronics really, it's not my field but I do know that my 12v DC motor should be turning on 12V and it is not. I'm not sure what the problem is really I need help. Is trying to power a 12v 1000rpm dc motor with a 12v a23 battery a mistake on my part? Or is my motor bust?

Comment: Do you have a multimeter?  Are you able to measure the voltage applied to the motor when connected to the battery?  The battery may not be able to deliver enough current and the voltage is dropping.  Is the motor turning at all?

Answer (score 2):

An A23 battery probably cannot deliver the current required by your motor.

Comment: Indeed, it's just a stack of small coin cells.